# Load first 3-5 images in lightgalleryjs dynamic mode

Tags: jquery, gallery, jquery-masonry, lightgallery-2

I'm changing the question after I found a `lightgalleryjs` which is more advanced than `fancybox`.

Is it possible to load first 3-5 images by default in dynamic mode than once the lightbox is opened the rest of images are loaded. So let's say if I have a gallery of 20 images I want to show the first couple of images in masonry way like the attached image with a view all link to view the rest of the images.

[image: masonry gallery]

I found a great jquery plugin to show gallery like facebook does ([click here to view the plugin page](https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Facebook-like-Photo-Grid-Plugin-With-jQuery-images-grid.html)). It shows the first 3-5 images and then generates a view all link to click and start sliding to view the rest of the images no matter how many images they are. The plugin comes with a default image modal to enlarge the image on fullscreen however I'm looking to merge both plugins loading the images as attached with the link to view the rest.

The HTML Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="https://www.cssscript.com/demo/sticky.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightgallery-bundle.css" />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/justifiedGallery@3.8.1/dist/css/justifiedGallery.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fb.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fb.js"></script>

        <style>
          body {
          padding: 40px;
          background-image: linear-gradient(#e8f0ff 0%, white 52.08%);
          color: #0e3481;
          min-height: 100vh;
        }
        
        .header .lead {
          max-width: 728px;
        }
        
        /** Below CSS is completely optional **/
        
        .gallery-item {
          width: 200px;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="gallery"></div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/justifiedGallery@3.8.1/dist/js/jquery.justifiedGallery.js'></script>
<script src="lightgallery.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/autoplay/lg-autoplay.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/comment/lg-comment.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/fullscreen/lg-fullscreen.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/hash/lg-hash.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/pager/lg-pager.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/rotate/lg-rotate.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/share/lg-share.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/thumbnail/lg-thumbnail.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/video/lg-video.umd.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/zoom/lg-zoom.umd.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // an array of images
                var images = [
                    {
                        src: 'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=874',      // url
                        alt: 'Two',          // alternative text
                        title: 'Two',        // title
                        subHtml: 'Two',  // modal caption
                        thumb: 'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=874', // thumbnail image url
                        'data-src': 'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=874',
                    }, 
                    {
                        src: 'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=872',      // url
                        alt: 'Three',          // alternative text
                        title: 'Three',        // title
                        subHtml: '',  // modal caption
                        thumb: 'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=872', // thumbnail image url
                        'data-src': 'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=872' // thumbnail image url
                    },     
                    {
                        src:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=868',      // url
                        alt: 'Car',          // alternative text
                        title: 'Car',        // title
                        subHtml: 'Supercar',  // modal caption
                        thumb:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=868', // thumbnail image url
                        'data-src':  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=868' // thumbnail image url
                    },
                    {
                        src:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=861',      // url
                        alt: 'Car',          // alternative text
                        title: 'Car',        // title
                        subHtml: 'Supercar',  // modal caption
                        thumb:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=861', // thumbnail image url
                        'data-src':  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=861' // thumbnail image url
                    },
                    {
                        src:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=827',      // url
                        alt: 'Five',          // alternative text
                        title: 'Car',        // title
                        subHtml: 'Supercar',  // modal caption
                        thumb:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=827', // thumbnail image url
                        'data-src': 'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=827' // thumbnail image url
                    },
                    {
                        src:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=844',      // url
                        alt: 'Six',          // alternative text
                        title: 'Car',        // title
                        subHtml: 'Supercar',  // modal caption
                        thumb:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=844', // thumbnail image url
                        'data-src':  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=844' // thumbnail image url
                    },
                    {
                        src:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=811',      // url
                        alt: 'Seven',          // alternative text
                        title: 'Car',        // title
                        subHtml: 'Supercar',  // modal caption
                        thumb:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=811', // thumbnail image url
                        'data-src':  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=811' // thumbnail image url
                    },
                    {
                        src:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=723',      // url
                        alt: 'Eight',          // alternative text
                        title: 'Car',        // title
                        subHtml: 'Supercar',  // modal caption
                        thumb:  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=723', // thumbnail image url
                        'data-src':  'https://unsplash.it/1300/800?image=723' // thumbnail image url
                    },    
                ];

                $('#gallery').imagesGrid({
                    images: images,

                    // align images with different sizes
                    align: false,

                    // max grid cells (1-6)
                    //cells: 3, 

                    // goto next image on click
                    nextOnClick: true,
                    
                    // callbacks
                    onGridRendered: $.noop,
                    onGridItemRendered: $.noop,
                    onGridLoaded: $.noop,
                    onModalImageUp: $.noop,
                });

            const $dynamicGallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
            const dynamicGallery = window.lightGallery($dynamicGallery, {
                dynamic: true,
                allowMediaOverlap: true,
                toggleThumb: true,
                animateThumb: false,
                showThumbByDefault: false,
                selector: '.image-wrap',
                plugins: [lgAutoplay, lgComment, lgFullscreen, lgHash, lgPager, lgRotate, lgShare, lgVideo, lgZoom, lgThumbnail],
                dynamicEl: [
                    {
                        images
                    },
                ]
            });
            $dynamicGallery.addEventListener("click", () => {
                dynamicGallery.openGallery(0);
            });
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The ImageGrid Plugin Code

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.imagesGrid = function(options) {

        var args = arguments;

        return this.each(function() {

            if ($.isPlainObject(options)) {
                var cfg = $.extend({}, $.fn.imagesGrid.defaults, options);
                cfg.element = $(this);

                this._imgsGridInst = new ImagesGrid(cfg);
                this._imgsGridInst.render();
                return;
            }

        });

    };

    $.fn.imagesGrid.defaults = {
        align: false,
        getViewAllText: function(imagesCount) {
            return 'View all ' + imagesCount + ' images';
        }
    };

    function ImagesGrid(cfg) {

        cfg = cfg || {};

        this.images = cfg.images;
        this.isAlign = cfg.align;
        if(cfg.cells) {
            this.maxGridCells = cfg.cells;
        } else {
            this.maxGridCells = 5;
        }
        
        this.imageLoadCount = 0;

        this.$window = $(window);
        this.$el = cfg.element;
        this.$gridItems = [];

        this.render = function() {

            this.setGridClass();
            this.renderGridImages();

            this.$window.on('resize', this.resize.bind(this));

        };

        this.setGridClass = function() {

            this.$el.removeClass(function(index, classNames) {
                if (/(imgs-grid-\d)/.test(classNames)) {
                    return RegExp.$1;
                }
            });

            var cellsCount = (this.images.length > this.maxGridCells)?
                this.maxGridCells: this.images.length;

            this.$el.addClass('imgs-grid imgs-grid-' + cellsCount);

        };

        this.renderGridImages = function() {

            if (!this.images) {
                return;
            }

            this.$el.empty();
            this.$gridItems = [];

            var i, item;
            for (i = 0; i < this.images.length; ++i) {

                var imgatt = 
                [
                    'src: "' +  this.images[i].src + '",',
                    'thumb: "' +  this.images[i].thumbnail + '",',
                    'subHtml: "' +  this.images[i].title + '",',

                ]

                if (i == this.maxGridCells) {
                    break;
                }

                item = $('<div>', {
                    class: 'imgs-grid-image',
                    data: { index: i }
                });
                item.append(
                    $('<a>', {
                        class: 'image-wrap',
                        id: 'image-wrap',
                        href: this.images[i].src,
                        'data-src': this.images[i].src,
                    }).append(
                        $('<img>', {
                          src: this.images[i].src,
                          alt: this.images[i].alt,
                          title: this.images[i].title,
                          load: this.imageLoaded.bind(this)
                        })
                    )
                );

                this.$gridItems.push(item);

            }
            const imgatts = imgatt.map(n => n);

            this.$el.append(this.$gridItems);

            if (this.images.length > this.maxGridCells) {
                this.renderViewAll();
            }

        };

        this.renderViewAll = function() {

            this.$el.find('.imgs-grid-image:last .image-wrap').append(
                $('<div>', {
                    class: 'view-all'
                }).append(
                    $('<span>', {
                        class: 'view-all-cover',
                    }),
                    $('<span>', {
                        class: 'view-all-text',
                        id: 'viewall',
                        text: cfg.getViewAllText(this.images.length)
                    })
                )
            );

        };


        this.resize = function(event) {
            if (this.isAlign) {
                this.align();
            }
        };

        

        this.imageLoaded = function() {
            ++this.imageLoadCount;
            if (this.imageLoadCount == this.$gridItems.length) {
                this.imageLoadCount = 0;
                this.allImagesLoaded()
            }
        };

        

        this.allImagesLoaded = function() {
            if (this.isAlign) {
                this.align();
            }
        };

        this.align = function() {

            var len = this.$gridItems.length;

            switch (len) {
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    this.alignItems(this.$gridItems);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.alignItems(this.$gridItems.slice(0, 2));
                    this.alignItems(this.$gridItems.slice(2));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.alignItems(this.$gridItems.slice(0, 3));
                    this.alignItems(this.$gridItems.slice(3));
                    break;
            }

        };

        this.alignItems = function(items) {

            var height = items.map(function(item) {
                return item.find('img').height();
            });

            var itemHeight = Math.min.apply(null, height);

            $(items).each(function() {

                var item = $(this),
                    imgWrap = item.find('.image-wrap'),
                    img = item.find('img'),
                    imgHeight = img.height();

                imgWrap.height(itemHeight);

                if (imgHeight > itemHeight) {
                    var top = Math.floor((imgHeight - itemHeight) / 2);
                    img.css({ top: -top });
                }

            });

        };

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sorry, but why do you think it is more advanced than Fancybox? I think they both have unique features, but Fancybox has more powerful API. And about your question - why don't you simply display first thumbnails, but make others hidden using CSS?

Comment: It's true Fancybox has a more powerful API however the lightgallery has more options and attributes for that. Besides fancybox works on the HTML side of the images while lightgallery works using jQuery and this will lower the resources usage. This is why I don't wanna show all images and then hide them via CSS. Let's say I have like 1000 images per page that's a lot of time for loading

Comment: But you do not have to load those images! You can create empty elements like `<div data-fancybox="gallery" data-src=".." />`

Comment: That's true however when triggering the gallery pop-up (modal) it reads only the listed images and not all